# Valid Val Names for Template Driven Extraction TDE

Tags: xml, types, marklogic

My question is how I can successfully apply a template to data that doesn't meet the XML specifications. I have incoming data with element names, values such as:

An example document, retrieved with fn:doc($uri):

```
{
"ID": "208455", 
"Type": "Deductions", 
"MONTH": "1", 
"2015 - Joe's": "14.10%", 
}
```

The part I would like to manipulate with my TDE is:

"2015 - Joe's": "14.10%"

Where the value itself is a string.

I would like to cast the value to a decimal, using a TDE template, by removing the "%" for example. This works when executed in query console:

```
let $s1:= "14.10%"

return fn:number(fn:replace($s1, "[^0-9.]", ""))

###
14.1 (float)
```

When executing the same chained functions inside the template however:

```
    <column>
      <name>value_2015</name>
      <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
      <val>fn:number(fn:replace(2015 - Joe's, "[^0-9.], ""))</val>
      <nullable>true</nullable>
    </column>
```

I receive an `Compile for Column value_2015='fn:replace(2015 - Joe's, "[^0-9.], "")' returns XDMP-BADCHAR: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected character found ''' (0x0027)` error. I believe this to be because the field name begins with a number and contains a " ' " character, in violation of [the XML specification over here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).

Consequently, I tried wrapping the element reference with "":

```
      <column>
      <name>value_2015</name>
      <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
      <val>fn:replace("2015 - Joe's", "[^0-9.], "")</val>
      <nullable>true</nullable>
```

but this of course returns another BADCHAR error: `XDMP-BADCHAR: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected character found '"' (0x0022)` since now we have quotation marks in the element reference.

How would I even go about fixing this? If I can't reference the elements, how would I replace them with valid XML element names? Do I have any options to like, escape the XML and tell the template to find a literal match for a given sequence of characters in the  argument?

Comment: Can you show an example of the source XML to which you are applying the TDE?

Comment: Added an example document that was retrieved with fn:doc($uri)

Answer (score 1):

Does it work to use node("2015 - Joe's") or text("2015 - Joe's") as the first argument to fn:replace()?

That should match the text value with a property name of "2015 - Joe's"

Comment: Thank you very much. The code snippet fn:replace(text("invalid xml's name"), "[^0-9.], "") as the argument to val seems to work exactly as expected. Apologies for the slow answer acceptance.